# srez実行で　Failed to remove a directory: train　のエラーの意味と解決法

Tags: python, tensorflow

srez実行してもましたが、下記エラー出ました。解決方法がわかりません。
どなたか、アドバイスいただきたいです。

※srez
https://github.com/david-gpu/srez

`C:\Users\wai\Documents\srez>python srez_main.py --run train` を実行

エラー

```
C:\Users\wai\Documents\srez>python srez_main.py --run train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "srez_main.py", line 190, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\wai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "srez_main.py", line 187, in main
    _train()
  File "srez_main.py", line 145, in _train
    all_filenames = prepare_dirs(delete_train_dir=True)
  File "srez_main.py", line 75, in prepare_dirs
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "C:\Users\wai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 366, in delete_recursively
    pywrap_tensorflow.DeleteRecursively(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "C:\Users\wai\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\wai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Failed to remove a directory: train
```

実行環境は下記のとおりです。
ＯＳ：Win8.1
Anaconda Nvigator 1.3.1　使用
python 3.5.2
tensorflow 1.0.1

ディレクトリ構成は下記です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ よければ、OSやpython、tensorflowのバージョンなどの環境情報を追記してくださいませんか？ 自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」を押すことで自由に書き直せます。

Comment: README.md に `The script will periodically output an example batch in PNG format onto the srez/train folder, ..`  と書いてあるので、権限・パーミッションなどの問題で `srez/train` フォルダが削除できないのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
管理者でコマンドプロンプト実行しましたが、下記エラーが同様にでました。

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd ../

・・・・・・・・・（途中略）

  File "C:\Users\wai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Failed to remove a directory: train

C:\Users\wai\Documents\srez>

Comment: コマンドラインから train ディレクトリを削除することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: コマンドラインから train ディレクトリを削除できました。

Comment: `train` ディレクトリを削除して `python srez_main.py --run train` を実行しても同様のエラーが発生するのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。train ディレクトリを削除して python srez_main.py --run train を実行しても同様のエラーが発生します。その後、かくにんすると、プログラムで自動的にtrain ディレクトリができています。

Answer (score 1):

git hubに投稿したissueにRandy Voetさんから下記回答メールきました。
これから、詳細確認予定ですが、なんとかなりそうです。

I had the same issue and fixed it by swapping prepare_dirs and setup_tensorflow in the _train and _demo functions of srez_main.py (sorry, no pull request yet for this). It seems that the creation of the FileWriter in setup_tensorflow causes a file to be created in the train folder, which is kept locked.
—
You are receiving this because you authored the thread.
Reply to this email directly, view it on GitHub, or mute the thread.

view it on GitHubは下記。
https://github.com/david-gpu/srez/issues/28
https://github.com/crimsonxiii/srez/commit/6cd9a31504ec8bedbfcb67a04562d58ca5768364